# featureLayer.UpdateCompleted problem?

Tags: c#, arcgis-silverlight-api

I am trying to show a particular kind of rendering to my geometry when a user clicks on the record of a feature data grid and zooms to the selection, but can't figure out what I am doing wrong...

Here is my code for the **featureLayerFromMap.UpdateCompleted += new System.EventHandler(fslayer_UpdateCompleted);**

```
void fslayer_UpdateCompleted(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
       ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.FeatureLayer featureLayerFromMap = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.FeatureLayer)(_mapService.Map.Layers["FeatureLayerControlLayer"]);            

        //*** Flashing of Polyline and Polygon when zoomed from a feature data grid record
        _objectIdDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        int count = 0;
        featureLayerFromMap.Graphics.ToList().ForEach(x => _objectIdDic.Add(x.Attributes["OBJECTID"].ToString(), count++.ToString()));

        if (featureLayerFromMap.Graphics.Count > 0)
        {
            if (featureLayerFromMap.Graphics[0].Geometry.GetType() == typeof(ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Polygon))
                featureLayerFromMap.Renderer = this._mapLayout.Resources["PolygonGraphicLyrSelectedRenderer"] as IRenderer;
            else if (featureLayerFromMap.Graphics[0].Geometry.GetType() == typeof(ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Polyline))
                featureLayerFromMap.Renderer = this._mapLayout.Resources["PolylineGraphicLyrSelectedRenderer"] as IRenderer;
        }
    }
```

The feature layer is provided from a selection in a combo box... Can someone guide me on this?